# Texmaker cannot load dictionary

Tags: texmaker, dictionaries

In texmaker, though I have configured the dictionary, i cannot still check the spelling, any idea??

[image]

Comment: I use Texmaker as well. I sometimes tried the check spelling option. But for me it didn't work either.

Comment: Depending on the Version of Texmaker you’re using (the current is 4.0), you might have to restart after switching the dictionary. If that doesn’t help, could you specify what the expected behavior is versus the behavior you’re getting?

Comment: i did it but getting the same error

Comment: @Noor Which error? (Don’t forget to `@username` other users when responding to their comments.)

Comment: @Noor i have my dictionary at `/usr/share/texmaker/en_US.dic` its provided by `TeXmaker` and its working.

Comment: @texenthusiast: I have no such file here with my Ubuntu installation.

Comment: I was never able to spell check my documents with Texmaker.

Comment: @juliohm Configure TeXmaker editor Spelling directory checking in `in-line` http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION03

Comment: @texenthusiast, my configuration is correct: `/usr/share/myspell/dicts/hyph_en_GB.dic` and the `inline` option is checked. It doesn't work.

Comment: @juliohm Although I have not much idea what's the issue(may be you are using OO provided `myspell` check), I suggest use the default spell check  provided by TeXmaker first(no need to download or install any custom spell checker), uninstall the TeXmaker fully and update to latest version of [TeXmaker 4.0.4 Aug 30 2013](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) and post any issue with clear demo at [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list) for more appropriate answer from Author.

Comment: The directory for you to choose depends on the dictionary you intend to use. Although myspell (/usr/share/myspell) seems to be very popular, I use hunspell (/usr/share/hunspell) as I had trouble configuring pt-br dictionary using myspell.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had the same problem but the `.dic` files that I used didn't work.

```
Texmaker Error : Can’t open the dictionary
```

To solve this error you need to install the spell-checker

- Use: `sudo apt-get install myspell-de-de myspell-en-us`
  or use `sudo apt-get install myspell-*`

---

on 4/8/23 Michael edited
I had to install hunspell
sudo apt-get install hunspell-en-gb
then i restarted TexMaker and under options->configure TexMaker I choose editor and under spelling dictionary I entered /usr/share/hunspell/en_GB.dic and now I can spell check on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS!!

---

- Then find the dictionary: `locate *.aff`

There were two directories that contained dictionary files in my computer; `/usr/share/hunspell/` and `/usr/share/myspell/`. Only one of the "myspell" dictionaries worked, while all the "hunspell" dictionaries worked (so far) .

Probably the `.dic` file from "myspell" doesn’t work without a corresponding `.aff` file...

- Chose the `.aff` file that you want and enter its path into texmaker at `options --> configure texmaker --> editor --> spelling dictionary` then click ok.
- Right click on your "code" and click on `check spelling` to make sure it's working.

Comment: This worked great for me. Thanks! It appears the default TexMaker folder for dictionaries is just wrong.

Comment: This worked for me. I used 

**sudo apt-get install myspell-de-de myspell-en-gb**

and then I redirected TexMaker to /usr/share/hunspell/

Comment: This did not work for me (Ubuntu 18.04.2, Gnome 3.28.2). Dictionaries are installed in /usr/share/hunspell/dicts/, Texmaker is pointed to the .dic file in that directory. Restarted Texmaker. Still get the error "can't open dictionary".

Comment: Cannot edit my comment, so adding another: the solution was to use the file icon in Texmaker to open the File manager and point to the .dic file, instead of typing in the path to the .dic file.

Comment: For recent Ubuntu it seems myspell is not maintained anymore. Hunspell works well on 20.04.

Answer (score 17):

`/usr/share/hyphen` are not the right directory for spelling dictionaries.
The spelling dictionaries are in the `/usr/share/myspell` directory and spell dictionaries are in fact always composed of 2 files: the `.dic` (which must be selected) and the `.aff` file.

Answer (score 10):

Inside `/usr/share/myspell/dicts` you should have links to both the .dic AND the .aff file of the language (e.g. `en_US` or `en_GB`).

```
/usr/share/myspell/dicts$ ls -og |  grep /en_US
lrwxrwxrwx 1 24 Jan 30 11:21 en_US.aff -> ../../hunspell/en_US.aff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 24 Nov  3 13:03 en_US.dic -> ../../hunspell/en_US.dic
```

Then from configuration, make TexMaker "Spelling dictionary" point to the `.dic` file:

`/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_US.dic`

This is the description/explanation from [MySpell Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySpell) entry:

> The spell checking is done using the .aff file for the locale together
>   with the .dic file. The .dic file is a list of words along with a
>   group of letters which refer to the affixes found in the .aff file.
>   This saves space because instead of having include all forms of a
>   word, like jump (jumping, jumps, jumped), the .dic file will include
>   the word once and the references to the affixes in the .aff file allow
>   the construction of all the other forms.

If you don't have an `.aff` file, you can get one the `en_US .dic/.aff` for [Hunspell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunspell) from [wordlist.sourceforge.net.](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wordlist/hunspell-en_US-7.1-0.zip)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and in my case I had to give a new path `/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.dic` to the dictionary since `/usr/share/hyphen/hyph_en_GB.dic` was non existent (on my ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks!! :)

Comment: Didn't work for Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 4):

I am using Texmaker 4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, and faced a similar problem; turns out that myspell-en-gb was not installed. Simple fix: `sudo apt-get install myspell-en-gb` and make sure the dictionary path is correctly set as `/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_GB.dic` in Texmaker's configuration window.

Answer (score 2):

To configure the spell checker: "Configure Texmaker" -> "Editor" -> "Spelling dictionary" -> click on the button at the end of the line to select the dictionary with the file browser. From the list pick the required dictionary; for my case `US-dic`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, solved it by using a different `.dic` file.

You can get it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wordlist/files/speller/).

```
Home -> speller -> [yyyy.mm.dd] -> hunspell(...).zip
```

[source](https://copiancestral.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/texmaker-error-cant-open-the-dictionary/)

Answer (score 2):

With **Ubuntu 16.04**, the spell check was not working for me. The config referred to a non-existent file.

Using `locate *.aff` I found `en_US.aff` in `/usr/share/hunspell`, fixed the config to this file and spell check is now working.

I am using TeXLive installed using [this](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu). See also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem just writing in the terminal `$locate *.aff`
and then change my directory in texmaker for the new one.

Answer (score 2):

(this should be a comment but i dont have reputation enough)

In my case, in `/usr/share/hunspell/` I have several files which are only symbolic links and some of then which are the actual files. The only one that work are the ones which are not symbolic links.

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue in Texmaker in my Ubuntu 16.04

There's just following simple steps to get rid of this.

1) Click options in the menu bar of your Texmaker window, and select `Configure Texmaker`

2) Click `Editor` in the leftmost column

3) Check whether the spelling dictionary bar ends with `en_GB.dic` or anything else other than `en_US.dic` (maybe Texmaker doesn't have in-built en_GB.dic installed - at least this was the case with me)

5) Install the `.dic` and `.aff` using `sudo apt-get install myspell-de-de myspell-en-gb`

6) The `.dic` file will normally be installed at `/usr/share/hunspell/en_GB.dic`. Or else you could just locate it.

7) Give `/usr/share/hunspell/en_GB.dic` to the spelling directory in the configure Texmaker and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I fixed it using the following approach:

Download an up-to-date spelling dictionary and make sure it includes the ".aff" file. You can get one from wordlist.sourceforge.net. Unzip, put it wherever you want, and then go to preferences->editor in texmaker and point to where you have your ".dic" file.